# How can I install typings folder angularjs1.5/typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm

I'm doing project with angularjs1.5 and typescript, need to install "angularjs/angular.d.ts" and "angularjs/angular-route.d.ts"  files. I installed tsd  globally, but after "tsd install angular" command i get message "Zero results". How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

tsd was deprecated in favor of typings.
typings then was deprecated in favour of @types.

Need use "npm install --save @types/angularjs" command.

Comment: "directive" should probably be "command". Also its probably best to save it as a development dependency instead of production (`--save-dev`). This ensures that when you deploy / restore packages on your test server or production server you do not deploy the typings which are only necessary on a dev. machine.